# batch file to list filenames and copy its content

Tags: batch-file

I need to copy content of all text files (more than 100) with their names in a file.

I know I can list names of files.

```
Dir  /b *.txt > Combine.txt
```

I can copy content of text files like it.

```
copy *.txt Combine.txt
```

But how to mix it?

I need    `Combine.txt`

```
file1.txt
Content of file1 
file2.txt
Content of file2 
file3.txt
Content of file3 
file4.txt
Content of file4
```

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it may not actually look exactly as in your example, I'd suggest you give the following a try:

```sh
find /v "" *.txt > allcontent.log
```

And to do that more correctly:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V "" "*.txt" 1>"allcontent.log"
```

The content would look a little more like this:

```
---------- FILE1.TXT
Content of file1 

---------- FILE2.TXT
Content of file2 

---------- FILE3.TXT
Content of file3 

---------- FILE4.TXT
Content of file4
```

As a side note, I changed the destination filename to use a `.log` extension, to not have the results try to include its own content, *(which would have happened had it also included the `.txt` extension)*.

Answer (score 0):

```
del 2>nul "output.xxx"&(for %J in (*.txt) do @>>output.xxx (echo %J&type "%J"))&move /y "output.xxx" "output.txt" >nul
```

from the prompt.

Since the output filename matches the mask `*.txt`, you need to generate the intermediate filename to a non-maskmatching name.

You may need to delete `output.txt` first to avoid including the original contents of that file in the result file.